# c++ operator overloaded argument vs normal argument

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, overloading, overload-resolution

I have a **function template** (c++)

```
template<typename T>
void print_to_default_file(T &obj, ADDON addon = "")
```

and a **overloaded function**

```
template<typename T>
void print_to_default_file(T &obj, std::string  objS) // or char* objS
```

The class `ADDON` has an operator overload of  the following signature

```
void operator=(const std::string)
```

The problem is that when I do
    print_to_default_file("test","where will I go")

**It is calling the first one**, but I want to call the second one. I have tired also with char * instead of std::string but the result is same.

Could anyone please point out what is wrong

ADDON simplified version

```
class ADDON {
    std::string s;

public:
    ADDON() {
        s = "";
    }

ADDON(std::string in) {
    s = in;
}

    ADDON(const char in[]) {
        s = in;
    }

    void operator=(const std::string in) {
        s = in;
    }

    std::string getString() {
        return s;
    }
};
```

Comment: I doubt this very much. Both versions require user-defined conversion, but the second requires just one, so should be the one that's called.

Comment: What compiler are you using? GCC considers the call to be ambiguous, see [here](http://ideone.com/QIRUjw)

Comment: @AndyProwl  I am using llvm 3.1

Comment: @AndyProwl in g++ the char* version is working properly

Comment: something else: deafault arguments are always passed, in your case the empty string literal by-value. this is slight performance bug (compiler might optimize it away if you don't use it). defining the default string outside the function and letting the default parameter to const reference would eliminate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Your original code does not compile

The code that you showed us

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ADDON {
    std::string s;

public:
    ADDON() {
        s = "";
    }

    ADDON(std::string in) {
        s = in;
    }

    ADDON(const char in[]) {
        s = in;
    }

    void operator=(const std::string in) {
        s = in;
    }

    std::string getString() {
        return s;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print_to_default_file(T &obj, ADDON addon = "")
{ std::cout << "first overload\n"; }

template<typename T>
void print_to_default_file(T &obj, std::string  objS) 
{ std::cout << "second overload\n"; }

int main()
{
     print_to_default_file("test","where will I go");
}
```

does not compile ([online output](http://ideone.com/8sil8A)) with the following error

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: prog.cpp:39:52: error: call of
>   overloaded ‘print_to_default_file(const char [5], const char [16])’ is
>   ambiguous prog.cpp:39:52: note: candidates are: prog.cpp:30:6: note:
>   void print_to_default_file(T&, ADDON) [with T = const char [5]]
>   prog.cpp:34:6: note: void print_to_default_file(T&, std::string) [with
>   T = const char [5]; std::string = std::basic_string]

The reason is that name lookup and argument deduction find 2 candidates: the first overload requires a `const char*` to `ADDON` conversion, and the second overload a `const char*` to `std::string` conversion. Both conversion sequences are equally good matches and overload resoution is ambiguous and your program ill-formed.

### A simple fix

Simply change the second overload to take a `const char*` as parameter (and not as `char*`, which cannot bind against string literals) and it will be the best match for raw string literals as argument

```
template<typename T>
void print_to_default_file(T &obj, const char*  objS) // but NOT char* objS
{ std::cout << "second overload\n"; }
```

You will now get the second overload ([online output](http://ideone.com/4G8VeM)). To select the first overload, simply call the `ADDON` constructor in the parameter list

```
int main()
{
     print_to_default_file("test", ADDON("where will I go"));
}
```

Note that this will call the `ADDON(const char[])` constructor and not the `ADDON(std::string)` one, since the latter will require a user-defined conversion ([online output](http://ideone.com/nw9jrG)).

### The proper fix

It is extremely dangerous to have non-explicit single argument constructors. Always use `explicit` keyword around such functions.

```
class ADDON {
    std::string s;

public:
    ADDON() {
        s = "";
    }

    explicit ADDON(std::string in) {
        s = in;
    }

    explicit ADDON(const char in[]) {
        s = in;
    }

    void operator=(const std::string in) {
        s = in;
    }

    std::string getString() {
        return s;
    }
};
```

This will also call the second overload ([online output](http://ideone.com/1zwhsu)), because the `ADDON` overload does not explicitly call any constructor. To select the first overload, again call the `ADDON` constructor in the parameter list.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have updated the code. Mostly its same as your post.

Comment: I am not getting this error. May be due the constructor. Please see the updated code

Comment: thank you for the effort. But still its not working, print_to_default_file("test", "where will I go"); is printing the constructor one. Please note that the compiler is llvm

Comment: @simpleuser Thanks, updated again. I changed the `operator=` into an explicit constructor taking a `const std::string`. The three linked examples now all call a different overload. Note that the `operator=` is used in assignments and it's usually not necessary to overload it for other arguments if you already have single-argument converting constructors.

Comment: also if I use ` explicit ADDON(const char in[])` I get the following error `error: no viable conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'ADDON'`

Comment: @rhalbersma: Why is `const char[]` to `std::string` not a user-defined conversion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fixed the answer and indicated 2 possible approaches.

Comment: @rhalbersma: You've got it now. +1

Comment: @rhalbersma Thank you. Thank worked. And thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I have accepted the answer

Comment: @simpleuser glad to have been of help!